# listing items on amazon using php?

Tags: xml, amazon-mws

I have read [this](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/XML_Documentation_Intl._V162213417_.pdf) and few other crappy tutorials that didn't help.  I love amazon.. but I am having a very hard time using their API and getting amazon to accept a "listItem" xml request.  I can't  get a returnString back from amazon and I'm not sure why.  Here is my Code:

```
$post_string = '<?xml version="1.0" ?>
  <AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amznenvelope.xsd">
  <Header>
  <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
  <MerchantIdentifier>' . $merchantID . '</MerchantIdentifier>
  </Header>
  <MessageType>Product</MessageType>
  <PurgeAndReplace>true</PurgeAndReplace>
  <Message>
    <MessageID>' . rand(1,1000) . '</MessageID>
    <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
  <Product>
    <SKU>'. $product->getSKU() .'</SKU>
    <ProductTaxCode>A_GEN_TAX</ProductTaxCode>
    <LaunchDate>'.date('Y-m-d') . 'T' . date('H:i:sO');'.</LaunchDate>
  <DescriptionData>
    <Title>'. $product->getName().'</Title>
    <Brand>'.$product->getBrand.'</Brand>
    <Description>' . $product->getDescription() . '</Description>
    <SearchTerms></SearchTerms>
    <SearchTerms></SearchTerms>
    <ItemType>flat-sheets</ItemType>
    <IsGiftWrapAvailable>false</IsGiftWrapAvailable>
    <IsGiftMessageAvailable>false</IsGiftMessageAvailable>
  </DescriptionData>i
  <ProductData>
  <Home>
  <Parentage>variation-parent</Parentage>
  <VariationData>
    <VariationTheme>Size-Color</VariationTheme>
    </VariationData>
    <Material></Material>
    <ThreadCount>500</ThreadCount>
    </Home>
    </ProductData>
    </Product>
    </Message>
  <Message>
  </AmazonEnvelope>';

$header  = "POST HTTP/1.0 \r\n";
$header .= "Content-type: text/xml \r\n";
$header .= "Content-length: ". strlen($post_string) ."\r\n";
$header .= "Content-transfer-encoding: text \r\n";
$header .= "Connection: close \r\n\r\n";
$header .= $post_string;


// Create a curl instance
$amazon_api = curl_init();

curl_setopt($amazon_api, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($amazon_api, CURLOPT_URL, "https://".$hosti."/");#."?$query_string" );
curl_setopt($amazon_api, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($amazon_api, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($amazon_api, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($amazon_api, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'OutdoorOutlet/1.0 (Language=PHP; Host=www.outdooroutlet.com)');

$returnString = trim(curl_exec($amazon_api));
```

Any suggestion on how to do this in an easier way or if there is some modules for php that I could use that would make listing easier.  If more code is needed, or more of an explanation of what im doing, just let me know.  I really don't know what my next step should be :(  Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Have a look at the Amazon MWS API specifically the Feeds API https://developer.amazonservices.com/

Comment: Hi @Ethan, did you get anywhere with this?  I can see that your XML syntax isn't correct, i.e. you have an opening <Message> right at the end for some reason?  Did you get it working in the end?  If so, could you post your example as I'm having trouble getting this to work too and Amazon won't help they just send me to Stackoverflow :s

Comment: Yep.  The Amazon schemas are incredibly inconsistent and horrible, and MWS / AWS API calls that **should** return something useful -- I'm looking at *you*, all of the MWS Products API's -- that actually aligns with their Feed schema declarations always seems to return a bunch of random garbage that has nothing to do with what the Product Feed is looking for by way of ProductData child nodes.  If they could just SOMEHOW MANAGE to return SOMETHING from a query that matched up with what the Feed REQUIRES I might be able to actually get something done this year...